# How to call Shell Script from Java Program using Hive JDBC

Tags: java, shell, hive

I have implemented a task in Hive.

But now I need to call a Shell Script which I have written for importing the tables in Hive from SQL Server using SQOOP. In that Shell Script I have written a SQOOP Command for importing the tables in HIve.

I tried to call a Shell Script in one of the Demo Application but as the Program runs no action taken place. I just see the blank console.

Do I need to do something extra in case of Hive?
Please help me out from this.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code you used to try calling the shell script from Java.

Comment: I have used it like this:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/hadoop/sqoop-1.3.0-cdh3u1/bin/TableToExport.sh");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run `/bin/sh /home/....TableToExport.sh`.

This explicitly defines the shell that interprets your script. This should work. 
If it does not work try to simplify your command line. Start from running simple command like `ls` or `hostname`. When it works try to execute something more complicated.

Generally it should work. You are on the right way.

Comment: How can I come to know that the command is executing??? Whether it will display something on console? or directly I have check the results everytime?